# Underline part of a string using NSMutableAttributedString in iOS 8 is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, nsmutableattributedstring

I try to underline part of a string, for example, a '*string*' part in '*test string*' string. I'm using `NSMutableAttributedString` and my solution was working well on `iOS7`.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:@"test string"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                         value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                         range:NSMakeRange(5, 6)];
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

The problem is that my solution is not working in `iOS8` anymore. After spending an hour on testing multiple variants of `NSMutableAttributedString`, I found out that this solution works only when range starts with 0 (length can differ). What is the reason for that? How can I workaround this?

Comment: resolve solution without appending : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27106188/2833978

Comment: As swift 5.1, you can look my answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift/65122584#65122584

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**Update:**
By investigating this question: [Displaying NSMutableAttributedString on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932632/displaying-nsmutableattributedstring-on-ios-8) I finally found the solution!

**You should add NSUnderlineStyleNone at the beginning of the string.**

Swift 4.2 (`none` was removed):

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "test ",
                                           attributes: [.underlineStyle: 0]))
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "s",
                                           attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]))
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "tring",
                                           attributes: [.underlineStyle: 0]))
```

Objective-C:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
 [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test "
                                                                          attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)}]];
 [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"s"
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                                                                                      NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]}]];
 [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"tring"]];
```

Another bonus of such approach is absence of any ranges. Very nice for localized strings.

Seems like it is Apple bug :(

Comment: I thought it was working, but unfortunately I ran the app in 7.1 simulator... Still not working on iOS8. But avoiding range is very nice, thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I didn't tested my code on iOS 8. But now I've done, and have finally found the solution.

Comment: how can remove underline after add

Comment: @HRaval, create a new string without underline.

Comment: but how can i direct text is underlined or not?

Comment: hey @kelin thanks for this answer.
Just a small correction 
`.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,`

Comment: @JeremyPiednoel, big thanks! Updated the answer for Swift 4.2.

Comment: The magic here is `.rawValue` on the NSUnderlineStyle "enum", passing in `NSUnderlineStyle.single` does nothing.

Answer (score 22):

I found that if you apply UnderlineStyleNone to the whole string you can then selectively apply underline to a part that starts in the middle:

```
func underlinedString(string: NSString, term: NSString) -> NSAttributedString {
    let output = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    let underlineRange = string.rangeOfString(term)
    output.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))
    output.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: underlineRange)

    return output
}
```

Comment: how can remove underline after add

Answer (score 6):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *signUpString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Not a member yet?Sign Up now"];

[signUpString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)}]];

[signUpString addAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x43484B),NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]} range:NSMakeRange(17,11)];

signUpLbl.attributedText = [signUpString copy];
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 5):

It's September 2018, so this answer is not about iOS8 but it still relates to underlining part of a string.

Here is a **Swift 4** extension that underlines a given term within an already composed `myAttributedString`

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func underline(term: String) {

        guard let underlineRange = string.range(of: term) else {

            return
        }

        let startPosition = string.distance(from: term.startIndex, to: underlineRange.lowerBound)
        let nsrange = NSRange(location: startPosition, length: term.count)

        addAttribute(
            .underlineStyle,
            value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
            range: nsrange)
    }
}
```

Usage: `myAttributedString.underline(term: "some term")`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5 version** of @Joss's answer with few modifications, by adding a returned NSMutableAttributedString, because I couldn't use the original solution without it.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

func underline(term: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    guard let underlineRange = string.range(of: term) else {
        return NSMutableAttributedString()
    }
    let startPosition = string.distance(from: term.startIndex, to: underlineRange.lowerBound)
    let nsrange = NSRange(location: startPosition, length: term.count)
    addAttribute(
        .underlineStyle,
        value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
        range: nsrange)
    return self
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
 let myUnderLinedText = "Hello World"
 let underLinedMutableString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: myUnderLinedText, attributes: titleAttributes).underline(term: myUnderLinedText)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let values = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "**YourString**")
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: values.length)
values.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: range)
```

This will make the string with underlined style, also you can replace the .underlinestyle and use .link to show it as a hyperlink in blue color

Answer (score 0):

I used the following extension (using exidy's function) in playground/simulator and it worked fine , you may change/add attributes depending on your needs

```
 extension NSMutableAttributedString
{


    func changeWordsColour(terms:[NSString])
{
    let string = self.string as NSString
    self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.brownColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.length))
    for term in terms
    {
        let underlineRange = string.rangeOfString(term as String)
        self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: underlineRange)

    }
}
}

 let myStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Change Words Colour")
 myStr.changeWordsColour(["change","Colour"])
```

Answer (score -2):

Add color for underline attribute:​​​

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName
                     value:[UIColor redColor]
                     range:NSMakeRange(5, 6)];
```