# Underlining an UIBarButtonItem does not work

Tags: ios, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to underline a `UIBarButtonItem`, but the following has no effect:

```
testBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue      
        ], forState: .Normal)
```

Changing other properties such as `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` does work.

The same code above used with an `NSAttributedString` and a `UILabel` does underline the text, so why does this not work with a `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: I can reproduce this in iOS 9/Xcode 7.  I tried setting the style to `.StyleNone` first (as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136157/underline-part-of-a-string-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-ios8-is-not-workin)), but that didn't help unfortunately.