# Unable to set UILabel attributes for a long title

Tags: xcode, user-interface, storyboard, uilabel

I'm currently in the process of creating my very first app. I am trying to create a `UILabel` which will have a section of it in bold in and in different colour. Nonetheless, when I try to add the bold and colour effect to the part of the string in `main.storyboard` file I am not able to as the `UILabel` shows me three dots (the part that I want to edit is after the three dots). To better illustrate my point please find here below a screenshot of my storyboard.[image]

So as you can see in the highlighted area after Invite your friends there are three dots so I am not able to edit the text coming after Invite your friends. (I tried double clicking on the label itself and edit from there but it sadly doesn't work). Is Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: It's better if you do that programmatically. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136157/underline-part-of-a-string-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-ios8-is-not-workin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you have provided do the following:

1. Close the project navigation on the left using the button on the left in the top 3 bottoms in the top right corner.
2. Hide the navigator that is now on the far left (which shows interface elements e.g. buttons e.t.c.)
3. Go to the line that separates the attributes inspector on the far right from the storyboard. Hover over it and move the mouse around a bit until you get two arrows going either way (or something like that).
4. Drag as far left as you can.
5. The attributes inspector is now very big, and you should be able to customise the full text as needed.